# VBA to count cells matching color and specific text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am trying to get VBA code to count cells in a range that match by cell fill color and by the text within.

I can get one criteria at a time easy enough, but every time I try to combine the conditions I get VALUE error. Please help!

This is what I have:

- G23-100 is the range
- F19 is the color and text to match

.

```
Function CountColorValue()
    Dim text As String
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("G23:G210")
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = Range("F19").Interior.ColorIndex Then
            If cell.text Like Range("F19").text Then
                text = text + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    Cells(1, 2).Value = numbers
End Function
```

It doesn't work, hence I am here..
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @Vape - are these cells formatted with Conditional Formatting or manually?

Comment: You can't change the value of a cell in a function. If you replace "Function" with "Sub" your routine should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not a function in fact, but a routine because you have no out put. You have multiple mistakes that I fixed without trying, it should work, if it did, please mark it as the correct answer on the upper left

```
Function CountColorValue() as integer
    Dim iColor as long, cnt as long
    Dim text As String, str as string
    Dim cell As Range
    iColor=Range("F19").Interior.ColorIndex
    str=Range("F19").value

    For Each cell In Range("G23:G210")
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = iColor and cell.text Like str  Then
            cnt=cnt+1
        End If 
     Next cell

     CountColorValue=cnt
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on my test, please try the VBA code as below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CountColorValue()
    Dim text As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("G23:G210")
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = Range("F19").Interior.ColorIndex And cell.text Like Range("F19").text Then
            text = text + 1
        End If
    Next cell
     Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = text
End Sub
```

Hopefully it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy and paste the code in a module.
2. Select the cell you want to have the results
3. Use this Function as the usally functions
4. The first Argument is the range you want to count, the second Argument is the cell with the interior.color you want to compare and the third Argument is the value or the cell you want to count the function in the range of first Argument. e.g =CountColorValue(G23:G210,$F$19,$F$19) or =CountColorValue(G23:G210,$F$19,"a")

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Function CountColorValue(Rng_dt As Range, criteria As Range, Val As Variant) As Double

   Application.Volatile

   Dim datar As Range
   Dim xcolor As Long
   xcolor = criteria.Interior.Color

   For Each datar In Rng_dt
   If datar.Interior.Color = xcolor And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(datar, Val) = 1 Then
   CountColorValue = CountColorValue + 1
   End If

   Next datar

   End Function
   ```